# Why is my nested class not accessible? (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, nested, inner-classes

I was trying to follow an example from the nested classes documentation: [Kotlin docs - Nested and inner classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/nested-classes.html)

So I tried:

```kotlin
fun main(){
    var tester = Test()
    println(tester.x) // 42
    tester.Foo().bar() // compiler error - unresolved reference: Foo!!!
}

class Test {
    var x:Int = 42
    class Foo {
        fun bar() = println("foobar!")
    }
}
```

However, the nested class was not accessible.
I'm obviously missing something really obvious.

Comment: Do you need a nested class or inner class? Nested classes are static, so you don't create them from instances, but simply by: `Test.Foo()`.

Comment: Yes! Can you make that ur answer? I just tried that out and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not trying to create an [inner class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/nested-classes.html#inner-classes), then a nested class should be referenced like so:

```
fun main() {
    var tester = Test()
    println(tester.x)  // 42

    // Static reference 
    Test.Foo().bar() // foobar!
}

class Test {
    var x:Int = 42
    inner class Foo {
        fun bar() = println("foobar!")
    }
}
```

As @broot said in his comment:

> Nested classes are static, so you don't create them from instances

Comment: I don't want an inner class? My Q title is about getting a vanilla nested class to work.

Comment: I see, if you don't want to use it as an inner class then you will need to reference it differently. See updated answer.

Comment: Would be best to remove the refs to inner classes in ur answer (or at least make it a footnote, because it's not the answer to the Q)... because that's how i got lost. A lot of examples of inner all over the net, and very little clarifications of this one aspect of NESTED that has been explained.

Comment: Yeah, that would be more helpful. I will also update your tag to nested-class instead of inner-class. (For whatever reason SOF considers inner and nested tags as aliases, which is not the same in Kotlin)

Comment: OMG... so i was the source of the confusion... sorry about that! Well that's just proof of how much inner is talked about over nested specifically, lol. My bad. Thanks muchly for ur patience!

Comment: No worries - SF considers "inner-classes" as alias to "nested-classes" which is not quite the "same" in Kotlin, so it redirected any of my "nested-classes" tag renames to "inner-classes", I have added "nested" tag in hopes to make things more clear to future users.

Comment: What is SOF?…..

Comment: @Tenfour04 My bad - SO* (StackOverflow) I keep getting this wrong for whatever reason. I can no longer edit my comments, if you have the permission to do so, please feel free.